# Coroutines in python

Tags: python, decorator, coroutine

I read the following code from a book, and have some questions about it.

```
def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        g = func(*args, **kwargs)
        g.next()
        return g
    return start

@coroutine
def receiver():
    print("Ready to receive")
    while True:
        n = (yield)
        print("Got %s" % n)

r = receiver()
r.send("hello, world")
```

By using `coroutine`, no initial `.next()` is needed. My understanding is, if `r = receiver()`, then `r = start`, so when I call `r.send()`, it equals to `start.send()`, then I call `.next()` again, right?  But the result is not what I expected.

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the coroutine.  You're misunderstanding the function decorator.  After `r = receiver()`, r is not start but g. Read up on function decoration and you'll understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you Rudd. Let me explain this with my understanding again. The call r = receiver() is equals to r = coroutune(receiver)(), which becomes r = start(), thus r finally is g. Is that right?